# how can I create objects of my class in swift based on json fetched by swiftyJson?

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have a class as follows:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class SingleRequest: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

var title: String?
let created: String
let discipline: String
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D


var items = NSMutableArray()


init(title: String, created: String, discipline: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.created = created
    self.discipline = discipline
    self.coordinate = coordinate

    super.init()
}
}
```

I also have a json that looks like:

```
[{"_id":"56c9d44fbcb42e075f7d49b1",
"username":"Ms. Brynlee Quitzon DDS",
"photo":"photo.jpg",
"number":"one",
"description":"Maiores rerum beatae molestiae autem. Voluptatem magni aspernatur est voluptas.",
"__v":0,
"updated_at":"2016-02-21T15:14:23.123Z",
"created_at":"2016-02-21T15:14:23.116Z",
"location":{
"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[5.300567929507009,44.04127433959841]}
},
etc.
```

and now I want to fetch all json entries and create `SingleRequest` object for each of them.

So far I created a method in this class:

```
class func getAllRequests() {
    print("getAllRequests")
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getRequests { json in
        let results = json//["username"]
        for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {
            let user: AnyObject = JSON.object



            var title = user["description"]
            let created = user["created_at"]
            let discipline = user["number"]

            let latitude = (user[""]).doubleValue
            let longitude = (user[""]).doubleValue
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

            return SingleRequest(title: title, created: created!, discipline: discipline!, coordinate: coordinate)


        }
    }
}
```

And now 2 questions:

1) as you can see above, I left those two fields empty:

```
let latitude = (user[""]).doubleValue
let longitude = (user[""]).doubleValue
```

that's because I don't know how to refer to the long/lat values from my json, since they are embeded in the `coordinates` field...

How can I fill it?

2) will this function create needed objects? or should I for example change the declaration to mark some return value:

```
class func getAllRequests()
```

? Thanks!

Comment: `coordinates` is an array, so you have to retrieve the `coordinates` array from the JSON dictionary and then access the two elements.  Since your fetch is going to execute asynchronously you can't return any values.  You should pass a completion handler closure to `getAllRequests`.  I would create an initialiser for `SingleRequest` (and probably `User` or something is a better class name) that accepts a dictionary rather than passing in all of those items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, you need to first get the array out of `user["coordinates"]` and then downcast it to Array, `user["coordinates"] as? Array<Double>`

For your second question, it should return an array of SingleRequest, `Array<SingleRequest>`

```
class func getAllRequests() -> Array<SingleRequest> {
    var requests: Array<SingleRequest> = [] 
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getRequests { json in
         let results = json//["username"]
         for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {
              let user: AnyObject = JSON.object

              var title = user["description"]
              let created = user["created_at"]
              let discipline = user["number"]

              guard let coordinates = user["coordinates"] as? Array<Double> else { print("no lat/long") }

              let latitude = coordinates[0]
              let longitude = coordinates[1]
              let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

              requests.append(SingleRequest(title: title, created: created!, discipline: discipline!, coordinate: coordinate))
        }
    }

    return requests
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var singleRequestsArray = [SingleRequest]()


class func getAllRequests() {

    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getRequests { json in

        for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in son {

            let user: AnyObject = subjson.object

            let title = user["description"]
            let created = user["created_at"]
            let discipline = user["number"]

            var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

            if let coordinates = user["coordinates"].array{

                let latitude = coordinates.first?).doubleValue
                let longitude = coordinates.array.last?).doubleValue
               coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            }

        singleRequestsArray.append(SingleRequest(title: title, created: created!, discipline: discipline!, coordinate: coordinate))

        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks! one more question - now this line `let latitude = (user["coordinates"].first).doubleValue` causes error that says `value of type 'AnyObject?' has no member 'first'` - is there any other way to do it then?

Comment: Have you tried with `let latitude = (user["coordinates"][0]).doubleValue` and `let longitude = (user["coordinates"][1]).doubleValue`  ?

Comment: @NiklasHein Downcast it to Array 'user["coordinates"] as? Array'

Comment: How could i downcast it here?

Comment: 'coordinate' let binding is only visible in if block but you're referring to it out of if @NiklasHein

Comment: 'append' method should be inside 'for' block @NiklasHein

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @user3766930 See my answer